# extracting data from .txt and writing it to .csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file with json tweets, 
every tweet is between ["text": & "is_quote_status":], 
i have manged to extract just the tweets, now i want to write the print output line by line to a csv.

```
import csv
with open('trumpT.csv', "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(trumpT.csv, delimiter=',')
with open('sim.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line.split('"text" :')[1].split(', "is_quote_status')[0]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Error
    writer = csv.writer(trumpT.csv, delimiter=',')
    NameError: name 'trumpT' is not defined

I able to get this part right but the csv is not working?

```
with open('sim.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split('"text" :')[1].split(', "is_quote_status')[0]
```

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: it seems you shoud replace `trumpT.csv` with `'trumpT.csv'` (need quotes)

Comment: it is in quotes!! i dont know why i am getting this error!!

Comment: i'm not talking about line 2 but line 3: `writer = csv.writer(trumpT.csv, delimiter=',')`

Comment: Now im getting a fresh error, writer = csv.writer('trumpT.csv', delimiter=',')
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Answer (score 2):

When using `with` take care to see until when you need that object,

> Python will then execute the code body, and no matter what happens in that code, call the guard object’s **exit** method.

So you have to do everything in the body of the `with` statement
your code should look like this:

```
import csv
with open('trumpT.csv', "wb") as csvfile, open('sim.txt', 'rb') as f:       
    writer = csv.writer(trumpT.csv, delimiter=',')
    for line in f:
        line.split('"text" :')[1].split(', "is_quote_status')[0]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Sources:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open("sim.txt", "r", newline='', encoding='utf8') as in_txt:
        in_reader = csv.reader(in_txt, delimiter = '\t')
        with open("trumpT.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as out_csv:
            out_writer = csv.writer(out_csv)
            for row in in_reader:
                row.split('"text" :')[1].split(', "is_quote_status')[0]
                out_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: thank you for this, i am getting an error--with open("sim.txt", "r", newline='', encoding='utf8') as in_txt:
TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Code was intended for version 3, I am assuming you're on 2. 
Try `with open("sim.txt", "rb")` instead

Answer (score 0):

This process can be made simple by using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Consider you have a valid json file at `/path/to/input.json` or `/path/to/input.txt`, file extension doesn't matters as far as a valid json is present.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("path/to/input.txt")
df[["text", "created_at_date"]].to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```